# await an anonymous function

Tags: asynchronous, dart

In the following code I can't find a solution to await for the inner asynchronous code. The result is that the data is always returned empty. Any ideas?

```
Future<Map> resolveLinks(links) async {
  var data = {};

  (links as Map).forEach((k, v) async {

    switch (v["type"]) {
      case "address":
      data[k] = await getAddress(v["value"]);
        break;
      case "person":
        data[k] = await getPerson(v["value"], v["subtype"]);
        break;
    }
  });
  return data;
}
```

Comment: It should just work fine, it you try to print the data inside the loop it gets printed properly? Also you shouldn't cast the links type, but just set the variable type in the function `Future<Map> resolveLinks(Map links) ...`

Comment: It doesn't work. The step by step debugging show that it returns the data then resolves it. It's always empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this won't work is because you inner function are returning Future objects you are never awaiting.

It should work if you modify your code to the following:

```
Future<Map> resolveLinks(links) async {
  var data = {};

  await Future.wait((links as Map).entries.map((entry) async {
    final k = entry.key;
    final v = entry.value;

    switch (v["type"]) {
      case "address":
        data[k] = await getAddress(v["value"]);
        break;
      case "person":
        data[k] = await getPerson(v["value"], v["subtype"]);
        break;
    }
  }));
  return data;
}
```

So instead of using forEach, I am using the map method on the entries iterable to map each entry into a Future object. When I takes all this Future objects and puts them into `Future.wait` which returns a Future there completes when all the other Future objects has returned its value.